# Do two different sessions get two different instances of JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a java application . I want to know if two different users log into the application , then the JSP they will get . Will that are two different instances of same JSP ? 
If no , Please explain .

Answer (score 0):

The servletcontainer **reuses the same servlet instance** for every request. So, there is only one instance of the servlet which is reused for multiple requests from multiple clients even across multiple sessions. Even if you do log out and log in again, it will use the same instance.

This is why it's important to write servlet code in a safe manner - which basically means using method local variables over instance variables because they will reused for multiple requests. I hope this helps.

Comment: If there is only one instance across different users , so it means threads are intiated to fulfill the requests and interference of data can be there among different users .

Comment: Correct. That is why we have to keep servlets thread safe by not letting them share instance variables.

Comment: I donot know whether this is a good question to ask , but in JSP pages we are not  advised to use `isThreadSafe` Directive as only one user at a time can view that page and rest others have to wait till that one have completed his request . So , is there some way we can make the page thread safe ?